# как создать базу данных через bat

Tags: база-данных, cmd, bat

есть файл id.txt в нем

```
pass: 12345678
name: Qwerty
```

как создать батник типа "текущий пароль: текущий uuid: хотите сменить" и перезаписывает их. не полностью файл а только "12345678" и "Qwerty" .не трогая pass и uuid, в любой последовательности, те я могу поменять pass и name местами и она будет работать. Можно использовать " , если не получается без них. сами слова могут быть не в 1 слове, а в нескольких. например:

```
pass: 1234 56 78
name: Qwer ty
```

полный код

```
@echo off
CLS
:menu

        echo 1 - Settings

    set /p m=
    if %m%==1 goto set
:set

        set /p s=Ssid:

    echo ssid %s%>ssid.txt

        set /p p=Pass:

    echo pass %p%>pass.txt

    for /f "UseBackQ tokens=1-2 delims==( " %%a in (%~dp0\1.txt) do if "%%a"=="ssid" set s=%%b
    for /f "UseBackQ tokens=1-2 delims==( " %%a in (%~dp0\1.txt) do if "%%a"=="pass" set p=%%b

        echo %s%
        echo %p%

    goto menu

pause
```

нужно из id.txt, создать

```
name: "Qwer ty"
pass: "1234 43 45"
```

если их нет. считать их. и вывести в cmd. после того как нажали на настройки ввести эти значения и изменить их в id.txt

Comment: Что уже сделано? Что именно не получилось?

Comment: я смог сделать только pass и uuid в отдельных файлах

Comment: Используйте FOR /F. Парсите каждую строку, записывайте параметр, если найден, в переменную среды. По завершении используйте переменные для вывода-корректировки. После чего выводите в новый файл.

Comment: команда   for /f "UseBackQ tokens=1-2 delims==( " %%a in (D:\winda\TochkaDostupa\ssid.txt) do if "%%a"=="ssid" set s=%%b умеет читать только одну строку и одно слово, как сделать так чтобы он читал весь txt

Comment: *умеет читать только одну строку* Сказки. Читается весь файл. По одной строке. Вот по одной и обрабатывайте - когда файл кончится, будут обработаны все строки. И включите SetLocal и EnableDelayedExpansion.

Comment: @Akina я когда делал раньше ничего не получалось. половина проблемы решено. теперь как сделать так, чтобы он считывал после ": " и считывал несколько слов в кавычках

Comment: *как сделать так, чтобы он считывал после ": "* Просто укажите "tokens=1,2" - в первый влетит "name:" или "pass:", во второй - значение. Каким боком тут вдруг кавычки - не понял...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions 
cls
if not exist ssid.txt goto :eof
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (ssid.txt) do (
    if /i "%%a"=="pass:" set pass=%%b
    if /i "%%a"=="name:" set name=%%b
    )
if "%name%"=="" goto :eof
if "%pass%"=="" goto :eof
set /p newname=Name is: %name%. Enter new name (Enter to keep) : 
set /p newpass=Password is: %pass%. Enter new password (Enter to keep) : 
if not "%newname%"=="" set name=%newname%
if not "%newpass%"=="" set pass=%newpass%
copy /y ssid.txt ssid.txt.bak
echo Name: %name% > ssid.txt
echo Pass: %pass% >> ssid.txt
echo Done.
```

Отлаживайтесь... в текущей реализации пробелы и табуляции в значениях не допускаются, никаких кавычек нет. Лишние строки из файла удаляются. Если есть несколько строк с именем или паролем - берётся только последняя.

Comment: а можно как нибуть с пробелами и с "" но чтобы "" не учитывались

Comment: Можно. Делайте. Суть будет та же. Просто выбирайте правильный delims. Например, это может быть `for /f "tokens=1* delims=:" %%a in (ssid.txt) do` - тогда в `%%b` попадёт всё, что после первого двоеточия, включая разделительный пробел (а он вообще нужен?).

Comment: для удобства оформления

Comment: Путей, которыми через батник в файл попадает хрень, немного. Кириллицу вводите небось? следите за кодировками. Ну и не сохраняйте батник в UTF+BOM.

Comment: можно как-нибудь подправить синтаксис на
Name: "слова с пробелом"
Pass: "слова с пробелом"
чтобы в батнике использовалось только в кавычках и с пробелами

Comment: как запретить использовать все символы кроме строчных прописных и цифр при написании в переменную

Comment: @Максим *при написании в переменную* В смысле - при выполнении `set /p`? Никак.

Comment: есть миниигра змейка. там можно так сделвть. но в коде много чего есть. я не могу его разобрать

Answer (score 1):

Я решил свою проблему благодаря пользователю [Akina](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/229437/akina)

Спасибо вам.

В моей базе данных можно использовать в переменных set только латинские буквы и цифры без пробелов, спец символов и Enter. Если их ввести, то будет ошибка, до тех пор пока не введут нормальные символы. (но все равно не рекомендуется спецсимволы использовать, особенно "<" и ">" из-за структуры cmd). Данные сохраняются в файл baza.txt в той же директории что и сам bat. Если baza.txt нет, то он создается с пустыми значениями. После ввода значений все сохраняется в baza.txt . После второго запуска можно будет увидеть предыдущие данные. Код на русском на английской раскладке, его можно русифицировать.

```
@echo off
SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
rem Chcp 866 >nul
title %~dp0
cd /d "%~dp0"

cls

if not exist Baza.txt (
echo Ne naiden fail "Baza.txt"
echo.
echo Sozdanie "Baza.txt" s pustuim znacheniem
echo.

echo Ssid:> Baza.txt
echo Pass:>> Baza.txt
)

for /f "tokens=1,2" %%a in (Baza.txt) do (
if /i "%%a"=="Pass:" set pass=%%b
if /i "%%a"=="Ssid:" set name=%%b
)




:1

echo Proshloe imya: %name%
echo.


set /p newname=Novoe imya: 

echo %newname%|>nul findstr /rc:"^[A-Z0-9a-z][A-Z0-9a-z]*$" && (
echo.
) || (
echo.
echo Nedopustimuij simvol
echo.
) && (
goto 1)

:2

echo Proshluij parol: %pass%
echo.

set /p newpass=Novuij parol: 

echo %newpass%|>nul findstr /rc:"^[A-Z0-9a-z][A-Z0-9a-z]*$" && (
echo.
) || (
echo.
echo Nedopustimuij simvol
echo.
) && (
goto 2)




if not "%newname%"=="" set name=%newname%
if not "%newpass%"=="" set pass=%newpass%
copy /y Baza.txt Baza.txt.bak
echo Ssid: %name%> Baza.txt
echo Pass: %pass%>> Baza.txt

pause
exit /B
```